# Flatten Hive struct column or avro file using pyspark

Tags: hive, pyspark, avro, apache-spark-sql

I have a Hive table which has a struct data type column(sample below). The table is created on avro file.

By using pyspark, how can I flatten the records so that I get simple data type value(not struct, array or list) in each column to load another Hive table.

I can use Hive table or avro file as source.

**Sample data-**

**Hive Column Name: Contract_Data**

```
{"contract":                    
    {"contractcode":"CCC",              
    unit:               
        {"value":"LOCAL",           
        desc:"LOCAL"},          
    segmentlist:                
        {"segment":[            #"segment" is array of struct here
            {"transaction":"1",     
            "plans":        
                {"identifier":[     #"identifier" is array of struct here
                    {"value":"123","desc":"L1"},
                    {"value":"456","desc":"L2"}]
                }   
            }]      
        }           
    },              
plans:                  
    {"listplans":[              #"listplans" is array of struct here
        {"plantype":"M",            
        plandesign:         
            {"value":"PV","desc":"PD"},     
            state:      
                {"value":"ST","desc":"ST"}  
            }]      
    }               
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first read the HIVE table as Spark Dataframe as below.

```
df = spark.table("<DB_NAME>.<Table_Name>")
```

then you can [explode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) function from Spark's Dataframe API to flatten the structure. PFB sample code which should work.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df.select(explode("Contract_Data"))
```

If the structure is nested which I could see in your above sample data, you can apply `explode` multiple times.

Hope it helps.

Regards,

Neeraj